# SublimeLinter JSHint stopped working

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

System configuration is:

- Win 7 x64
- SublimeText 3
- SublimeLinter-JSHint

Everything was installed properly and worked fine (node.js, jshint installed through npm). At some point the linter just stopped seeing JS syntax errors.

Except for JSHint, some other linters are installed and work fine - PEP8, CSSLinter. No errors in console regarding broken stuff. Reinstallation of JSHint didn't fix things.

How to diagnose the problem and make the linter work?

Comment: "*At some point the linter just stopped*". And what did you do at that point? Computers **always** do things for a reason. They don't "just stop" with no explanation.

Comment: @MattDMo - thanks for trying to 'help'. Down-voting questions is what StackOverflow was created for - keep up the good work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about building a library of useful programming questions with specific and detailed answers. It is community-moderated so that the best questions and answers rise to the top, and the rest don't. Your question is far too vague and broad, *as evidenced* by the fact that it was solved by changing the settings for a plugin **you didn't even mention you had installed**. If you had answered my question by saying, "*Well, I did install this plugin the day before...*" then maybe someone could have helped you. Feel free to keep complaining about the "downvote culture", though...

Comment: The plugin was installed 2 month ago, and the problem occurred 2 days ago - there is no clear logical chain. If it was so easy - the question wouldn't be asked. Sometimes after searching the web for a day - one runs out of ideas and the only was is to post question - so may be someone has experienced something similar and can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 day of searches in Google I've managed to find solution. The page with Global Settings brought some light on the problem:
https://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/global_settings.html#syntax-map

The cause of problem was another package, that messed up JavaScript syntax after some update.